# What is the PhpStorm Shortcut to Open View by Clicking it or Selecting it

Tags: ide, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, I'm unable to find the shortcut that allows you to click or select a view, that will open or navigate to that view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. No real clue on what you are talking about. Can you please illustrate that "view" with a screenshot or two?

Comment: Not sure about your question, but maybe are you talking about the Preview in browser (ALT+F2)?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, the solution is a paid plugin for Laravel named Laravel Idea.  It has been worth every penny...

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea